# Cannot access server on LAN remotely via VPN Tunnel (when server has VPN client turned on)

Tags: networking, router, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I have a self-hosted server which has an openVPN client connection always on. So the public IP of this server is not the same as all the other devices connected to the router.

I want to also access this server remotely with a VPN Tunnel I created on my router (acting as a VPN server). This VPN tunnel is working because I can access the router's gateway remotely.

However, I cannot access the local server that has the VPN client connection. When I disable this VPN client... then I can access `http://<server-IP>:<web-app port>` remotely.

Is there a way to fix this. I realise that since the VPN server on router has a specific public IP while the local server has a different one (due to VPN client) this might be the reason why I cannot access it through the Tunnel.

Any solutions I can use while keeping this VPN Client connection on?

### Details

- Router: TP-Link Archer C7 with VPN server
- Home server on static ip: `192.168.1.111`

  - This server has an openVPN connection always on from configuration files I have from a VPN subscription (proton vpn).
- I can access this server locally both with `ssh` connection (`ssh user@192.168.1.111`) and via URL to a web app hosted on this server `http://192.168.1.111:8066`
- When I am not inside LAN, I switch on openVPN tunnel and go to `http://192.168.1.111:8066` but this never loads.
- **however**, If I switch off the openVPN client on `192.168.1.111` and try again remotely, as the above step, It works and I can access the web app

Comment: Are you using Microsoft VPN?  That would cause what you see.

Comment: @BlindSpots yes I can access the server locally with another machine even when the server has an openVPN client on. I will add more details to the question

Comment: Can you show us your server `conf` or `ovpn`?

Comment: I'm obviously not going to share it fully, but if there are parts of it you think I should look into and any pointers as to what might be wrong in the file I would appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional info.  When you come in through your router's port forwarding, you are still an internet user.  The server sends its traffic to the internet via configured gateway which is the VPN when connected or the router when VPN is disconnected.  You also may have issues with internet traffic accessing the server locally while the VPN is running unless the source network IP or range has been whitelisted. Determine what is going on with the traffic.  Is it being dropped by the server?  misdirected? etc.  Start with Proton and see what the options are.